# How can I create a full-width VStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a body with a VStack, another VStack inside that I'd like to start 20 points in, just like my "Explore More" text but for some reason it's indented like this and I can't figure out why. Would love some help here.

```
    struct BrandExploreMore: View {

    let brand: Brand

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Explore More")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(BrandColors.titleGray.color)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                Spacer()
            }

            VStack(spacing: 12) {
                Grid(leftTitle: "Desert", rightTitle: "Kids")
                Grid(leftTitle: "Stripes", rightTitle: "Pastels")
            }
             //.padding(.horizontal, 20)
//            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -40, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .background(SwiftUI.Color.red)
        }.background(SwiftUI.Color.orange) // end VStack
    }

}

struct BrandExploreMore_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BrandExploreMore(brand: .kateZaremba)
    }
}

// MARK: - Grid

struct Grid: View {

    let leftTitle: String
    let rightTitle: String

    @State private var showLeft = false
    @State private var showRight = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
//            Spacer()
            Button(action: { self.showLeft = true }) {
                ZStack {
                    Image(leftTitle)
                    Text(leftTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(BrandColors.titleGray.color)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showLeft) {
                Text(self.leftTitle)
            }

            Button(action: { self.showRight = true }) {
                ZStack {
                    Image(rightTitle)
                    Text(rightTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(BrandColors.titleGray.color)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showRight) {
                Text(self.rightTitle)
            }
//            Spacer()
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that you have for the `GridView` as that may be affecting padding that you have in the second `VStack`? Have you tried taking the padding off of the second `VStack`?

Comment: I updated the code and the image above

Comment: Can you show me how it should be?

Comment: It should have a left border same as the beginning of the explore more text (20 pts) and a right margin to the edge of 20 pts

Comment: Your code is full of undefined resources, can you manage it if I give you a template with regular elements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Undefined resources?

Comment: Images, colors..., the output of the code you provided is not same with the image.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier you need is `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` for anything you need to stretch to fill.

In your code:

- Each `Button` in the `Grid`
- The middle `VStack(spacing: 12)` in `BrandExploreMore`

---

So after removing unknown resources and cleaning your code and performing some refactoring to it:

```
struct BrandExploreMore: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Group {
            Text("Explore More")

            VStack(spacing: 12) {
                Grid(leftTitle: "Desert", rightTitle: "Kids")
                Grid(leftTitle: "Stripes", rightTitle: "Pastels")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .background(SwiftUI.Color.red)
            }.padding(.horizontal, 12)
        }
            .background(SwiftUI.Color.orange) // end VStack
    }

}

struct BrandExploreMore_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BrandExploreMore()
    }
}

// MARK: - Grid

struct Grid: View {

    let leftTitle: String
    let rightTitle: String

    @State private var showLeft = false
    @State private var showRight = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            Button(action: { self.showLeft = true }) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 100)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                    Text(leftTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showLeft) {
                Text(self.leftTitle)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            Button(action: { self.showRight = true }) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 100)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                    Text(rightTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showRight) {
                Text(self.rightTitle)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting this:
[image: Demo]